# Parsing Dates from Float in Python

Tags: python, date, parsing, datetime, forecasting

I have the following data ( actually AirPassengers from http://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/datasets.html)

```
     time             AirPassengers
1   1949.000000            112
2   1949.083333            118
3   1949.166667            132
4   1949.250000            129
5   1949.333333            121
6   1949.416667            135
```

How do I parse the time column in Python to be a date (TS) and not a float. I need this as a basic step before I start time series forecasting

Based on comments
Time is in years and is a float (1949.000 is Jan 1949 and 1949.0833 is Feb 1949)

I am using this to import data, I dont know how to use the date parser within  read_csv

```
series = read_csv('http://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/datasets/AirPassengers.csv', header=0, parse_dates=[0], index_col=0, squeeze=True, )
```

Updated-

one possible solution- ignore the float value and create a date time series using beginning, end and time interval

```
series['dates']=pd.date_range('1949-01', '1961-01', freq='M')
series.head()

time    AirPassengers   dates
1   1949.000000 112 1949-01-31
2   1949.083333 118 1949-02-28
3   1949.166667 132 1949-03-31
4   1949.250000 129 1949-04-30
5   1949.333333 121 1949-05-31
In [45]:

series.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 144 entries, 1 to 144
Data columns (total 3 columns):
time             144 non-null float64
AirPassengers    144 non-null int64
dates            144 non-null datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(1), int64(1)
memory usage: 4.5 KB
```

Note the new problem- shows end day of month (not beginning) and our original problem of turning float values into datetime values remain

Python version

```
!pip install version_information
%load_ext version_information
%version_information


Software    Version
Python  3.5.2 64bit [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
IPython 5.1.0
OS  Windows 7 6.1.7600 SP0
```

Comment: Which format is that?

Comment: What time is 1949.0 supposed to represent? 1,949 seconds after the Unix epoch? The 19th day of the year '49? 19 hours and 49 minutes after midnight? We have no way of knowing.

Comment: What unit is the time expressed in? From the link it would look like it's 1949 as a year? Can you give an example of the expected format?

Comment: expected format would be 1-1-1949 in a TS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your input data isn't very precise. It's just :

```
1949 + float(month)/12
```

You could just iterate over your line numbers :

```
import datetime
start_year = 1949
for line_number in range(20):
    print datetime.date(start_year + line_number/12, line_number % 12 + 1 , 1)
```

It outputs :

```
1949-01-01
1949-02-01
1949-03-01
1949-04-01
1949-05-01
1949-06-01
1949-07-01
1949-08-01
1949-09-01
1949-10-01
1949-11-01
1949-12-01
1950-01-01
1950-02-01
1950-03-01
1950-04-01
1950-05-01
1950-06-01
1950-07-01
1950-08-01
```

If you really want to parse the strings, you could try :

```
import datetime

year_str = "1949.166667"
year_float = float(year_str)
year = int(year_float)
year_start = datetime.date(year,1,1)
delta = datetime.timedelta(days = int((year_float-year)*365) )

print year_start + delta
# 1949-03-02
```

This way, the steps between datapoints will be exactly a 1/12th of a year.

Comment: I get this TypeError: integer argument expected, got float

Comment: Which Python version do you use?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose,

```
1949.000  = 1st jan 1949
```

and

```
1949.9999... = 31th dec 1949
```

Also, as Eric Duminil pointed out, your values seem to be month-rounded.
If that is true, then you can do something like this:

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def floatToDate(date_as_float):
    year = int(date_as_float)
    months_offset = round((date_as_float - float(year)) * 12.0, 0)
    new_date = datetime.datetime(year,01,01,0,0,0,0)
    new_date = new_date + relativedelta(months=int(months_offset))
    return new_date

converted = floatToDate(1949.083333) # datetime 01-feb-1949
```